# What are some breweries locals like to visit in New York City?

Tags: breweries, recommendations

I wasn't a beer enthusiast while living in NYC, but still I don't recall hearing much about local breweries. Are there any worthwhile beers brewed in NYC, worth visiting at their sources?

Looking to hear from people who have actually visited breweries in NYC, since anyone could just Google "breweries in NYC". A local might take into consideration breweries which are easily accessible via the subway system, or breweries in fun neighborhoods, not some desolate industrial park in Brooklyn (unless that's part of the appeal) or a shady neighborhood in the Bronx.

Comment: This question is just going to generate a list of opinions, I think.

Comment: @jonsca - Does the edit make it somewhat more acceptable?

Comment: There's still quite a bit of "subjectiveness" to the question, with regards to what constitutes "good", "tasty", "well-known","fun neighborhoods", etc., but I think that you've narrowed it down quite a bit.  I think it's a great question at its core, it's just a question of how useful it will be to someone in the future...

Comment: @jonsca - Unfortunately, I agree; I guess some subjectivity can't be helped here. As to its usefulness though, besides me, I can definitely imagine others visiting NYC and wondering about breweries. Hopefully when they search "breweries in NYC," this question will be the first hit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brew York (which is one of the foremost local news sites for Beer Enthusiasts in NYC) wrote up a really great [guide to NYC's Beer Culture](http://brewyorknewyork.com/post/74950465749/the-super-bowl-visitors-guide-to-craft-beer-in-new) for Super Bowl visitors last week.

The strongest picks, if I had to rattle them off myself, would be [Brooklyn Brewery](http://brooklynbrewery.com/visit/visiting-the-brooklyn-brewery) for someplace with some serious scale, [Singlecut's taproom](http://www.singlecutbeer.com) in Astoria for some great hoppy lagers and the best in-brewery drinking experience in town, and [Peekskill Brewery](http://peekskillbrewery.com) and [Barrier Brewery](http://www.barrierbrewing.com/Site/HOME.html) if you're willing to spend 30 minutes on a commuter rail line (Metro North or LIRR respectively), for two of the most daring and inventive brewers in the region.

Really though, even though NYC has a number of local breweries, it isn't a great place for drinking *at the source* -  beer culture in the city, while heavily local, is largely centered around a number of fantastic bars; Check out [Torst](http://www.torstnyc.com/), [Barcade](http://barcadebrooklyn.com/), [Spuyten Duyvil](http://www.spuytenduyvilnyc.com/), [Alewife](http://alewifenyc.com/), [The Pony Bar](http://theponybar.com/), [Blind Tiger](http://www.blindtigeralehouse.com/), [the Ginger Man](http://www.gingerman-ny.com/), [Burp Castle](http://burpcastlenyc.wordpress.com/), or any of the [tons and tons of other great venues.](http://brewyorknewyork.com/barsandbreweries)

The [Craft Beer New York](http://bluecrowmedia.com/#cbny) app for both major smartphone platforms is also excellent, with up to date listings on new bar and brewery openings, local events, limited releases, and more. Easily worth a few bucks for any serious enthusiast.

Comment: While you're on the topic of Long Island, I'm going to take the liberty of making some recommendations as I live there. Port Jeff Brewery is currently my favorite local brewery (you have to try the Schooner Ale and the White's Beach Wit). Also, if you see it on tap, try the Runaway Ferry smoked IPA, it tastes like bacon IMO! Crooked Ladder in Riverhead is also pretty good, but no comparison to Port Jeff. Long Ireland is ok, but nothing worth going out of your way for. After Port Jeff, I'd recommend Southampton Publik House. I can't recommend Blue Point after their recent sellout to In-Bev

Comment: http://www.longislandbeerguide.com/ Has a good summary of the beer life here on the Island

Answer (score 2):

Here is a decent [blog](http://blogs.villagevoice.com/forkintheroad/2013/07/10_best_breweries_in_nyc_2013.php?page=3). It has been some time since I was in NYC, but, Brooklyn Brewery produces many good beers and i recommend visiting them. [Here](http://brooklynbrewery.com/visit/visiting-the-brooklyn-brewery) is their schedule